# Как организовать рабочий процесс небольшой команды?

Tags: php, .net, crm, teamcity, jira

Здравствуйте.
Образовалась небольшая команда. Постоянно работаем над разными проектами, иногда с привлечением внешних ресурсов. Последние время в организации работы полный хаус. Хотелось бы все привести в некоторый логический порядок. Посему хотелось бы услышать ваши советы.
Используем в разработке Scrum, сложные проекты обязательно проходят тесты. В основном web-проекты, иногда прикладные программы. Работаем с php и .NET (дизайн и верстка присутствуют). Постоянно идет обсуждения рабочих моментов в чате whatsapp.

Поэтому сформировалась такая позиция: 
Сайт через веб-форму взаимодействует CRM Zoho. В CRM распределяются заказы, ведется статистика и собираются полезные контакты. 
Для внутреннего взаимодействия ставится на сервер Jira c Agile надстройкой. Для уведомлений и переписки - HipChat. В качестве репозитория - BitBucket (хорошо интегрируется с Jira+HipChat). Для крупных проектов организуем CI на базе TeamCity (поставим себе на сервер). 
Из расходов: выделенный сервер и лицензии для Jira c Agile надстройкой. 
По идее все хорошо интегрируется, кроме Zoho.

Еще кстати рассматривали Visual studio online, но делать прохват, к примеру, от webstorm'a до их системы через teamcity выглядит монстроидально. К тому же нет мобильного клиента для встроенной системы чатов. Есть открытый проект на Xamarin. Но как-то нет желания самостоятельно поддерживать клиент для 3 ОС.

А как вы думаете?

Comment: Так вы уже со всем определились, судя по тексту.

Comment: Мы пока просто свой вариант подобрали. Хотелось бы увидеть как это выглядит в других командах.

Comment: Завязочка у Вас совсем недурно оформлена). На самом деле нет единых подходов тут. В каждой веб-студии, если вы придете работать используют свои технологии, наработки. Потому трудно и однозначно сказать верно ли вы выбрали технологии и организовали свой бизнес-процесс проектирования ПО. Только опыт поможет Вам скоординировать дальнейшие действия, плюс еще не забываем про экономическую составляющую на рынке веб-технологий. Добиваются успеха лучшие, слабые погибают).